# Android Design Support Library: Use ViewPager/TabLayout with scrolling toolbar and sticky button

Tags: android, android-design-library

I have a TabLayout combined with an ViewPager. In the tabs some Fragments are displayed. One Fragment consist of a NestedScrollView and a sticky button which should always be visible, even if the user scrolls down/up. 
Additionally I would like to hide the toolbar, if the user scrolls down.

Currently the scrolling works, but my sticky button is not visible at startup and appears only, if I scroll down.

This is my setup (basically taken from Chris Banes cheese-sample https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare):

**The layout containing the ViewPager and the Toolbar:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**My fragment with a NestedScrollView and a Sticky Button:**

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Item 1" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Item 2" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Item 3" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Item 4" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Item 5" />

  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<Button
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="52dp"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  android:text="Button" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The result I would like to achieve (initial state after startup) - Button with text "Button" should show up - please ignore the FAB:

[image: Result to achieve]

This is the result I currently get - button with text "Button" not visible -  please ignore the FAB:

[image: current result]

If I scroll down my button "Button" should remain visible and the toolbar should collapse:

[image: after scrolling]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Don't you think `Snackbar` is the answer to your question?

Comment: Or you want to show this button at all times? I think you might consider a little redesign.

Comment: This button should always be visible. There is no need for a redesign. Please consider that these screenshot are from the adopted cheesecake-app of Chris Banes. This is not the design of my current app. But I shows the same misbehavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need put your sticky button into root CoordinatorLayout with attribute

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

or make bottom margin of sticky button which equals `?android:actionBarSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `NestedScrollView` like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

and set `Button` like this

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="52dp"
 android:elevation="10dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 android:text="Button" />
```

And let me know if this works

Comment: I did this but the scrolling behaviour stop working when adding marginBottom to NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment take parent as relative layout put button in Framelayout and put `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` this to Framelayout.

```
     <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="Item 1" />

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="Item 2" />

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="Item 3" />

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="Item 4" />

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="Item 5" />

      </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/test"   
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="52dp"
      android:text="Button" />
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Try this code i modify it.